# How to change a URL for a specific page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not talking about site URL.

I mean like changing from `mysite.com/our-team/john-doe` to `mysite.com/our-volunteers/john-doe`

I just want to rename the /our-team/ to /our-volunteers/. There's only one john-doe page. Now, John Doe is NOT our team per se, but he's a volunteer. So, I need to change the slug to "our volunteers."

The current premium I'm using does not create a WordPress typical page for this so I can't modify the url of the page. So, this does not work -> https://www.competethemes.com/blog/change-page-url-wordpress/

Is there like a hook i can use? Permalinks only allow changing the url structure of the entire site.

Comment: do you mean globally or on a page by page basis? Did you check the permalink parameters in your WP Dashboard?

Comment: @gael My question title said specific page. Permalinks is for entire site.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Are there other `john-doe` pages? Should they stay in `our-team` section or should they move to? If there is no page called `our-team` it must be set somewhere???

Comment: @gael I just want to rename the /our-team/ to /our-volunteers/. There's only one john-doe

Comment: @gael. If there's no john doe, it will show page not found. Or if someone goes to our-team only, then page not found too.

Answer (score 0):

One hack could be to edit .htaccess for this particular issue. It's kinda hacky and might get you into other problems. There's also plugins to do rewrites for you.

Comment: I agree with @amrography – that's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you exactly looking for is Page attributes

https://wordpress.com/support/pages/page-options/#parent-page

---

You have parent page Our volunteers

http://example.com/our-volunteers

And pages of children pages

- http://example.com/our-volunteers/john-doe
- http://example.com/our-volunteers/foo
- http://example.com/our-volunteers/bar

Set `our-volunteers` as page slug when you create **Our volunteers** page

Assign pages **John doe, foo, bar** to Parent page (Our volunteers) from Page attributes section bottom right on 'creating new page' page

[image]